# Perform Join and Group with Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

Hey all.  I'm not sure how I could express the following query in C# using Linq to SQL.  Here is a short snippet of the pure SQL:

```
select t1.WholesalerID, t1.RetailerID,
    sum(t1.Col1) as 'Column 1',
    sum(t2.Col1) as 'Other Column 1',
    (sum(t1.Col1) - sum(t2.Col1)) as 'Column 1 Difference',
    sum(t1.Col2) as 'Column 2',
    sum(t2.Col2) as 'Other Column 2',
    (sum(t1.Col2) - sum(t2.Col2)) as 'Column 2 Difference'
    from Table1 t1
    inner join Table2 t2 on t1.WholesalerID = t2.WholesalerID
group by t1.WholesalerID, t1.RetailerID
```

Now, I've done Linq to SQL joins and group by's before, but I'm sure how to go about doing these together.  I run into the problem when I'm attempting to sum the values from the joined tables.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this may be naive but why do you actually want to use LINQ if you already have a ready SQL query. It should be easy enough to just use it. See: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001281.html

Comment: I would like to stick with Linq for the sheer fact that it is what I have been using all along, and if at all possible, I would like to not deviate from it.  Thanks.

Comment: hm... so you would like to shoot yourself in the left foot, in the right foot or in both?

Comment: For the most part, the queries have been relatively trivial queries, so, it wasn't until I encountered this that I became a little stumped.

Comment: I've yet to be convinced of the point of Linq2SQL (Linq2Other may be great). Why learn a whole new syntax that doesn't seem to add any actual new functionality, especially when it's usually preferable to embed the complicated stuff in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reached this solution: (didn't tested it though)

```
        var qry = from t in
                      (from t1 in Table1
                       join t2 in Table2 on t1.WholesalerID equals t2.WholesalerID
                       select new { t1, t2 })
                  group t by new { t.t1.WholesalerID, t.t1.RetailerID } into g
                  select new MyTypeWithDifferenceProp
                  {
                      WholesalerID = g.Key.WholesalerID,
                      RetailerID = g.Key.RetailerID,
                      Column1 = g.Sum(e => e.t1.Col1),
                      OtherColumn1 = g.Sum(e => e.t2.Col1),
                      Column2 = g.Sum(e => e.t1.Col2),
                      OtherColumn2 = g.Sum(e => e.t2.Col2),
                  };
```

This `MyTypeWithDifferenceProp` would have the `Column1Difference` and `Column2Difference` already defined.